# debugging richfaces/jsf project

Tags: java, debugging, jsf, richfaces

can anyone please tell me method to debug richfaces or jsf project?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- add Tomcat (or whatever container you are using) in your Servets in eclipse (or whatever IDE you are using)
- start the server in debug mode and deploy the application
- put a breakpoint in your controller methods.

Answer (score 1):

Debugging jsf projects involves server side and client side debugging.

For server side debugging I go along with Bozho's answer.

For the client side I recommend Chrome's developer tools (integrated) or the [Firebug add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/firebug/) for Firefox.